# debouncing in react using useRef and useMemo

Tags: javascript, reactjs, debouncing

I am trying to implement debounce in react js , and I have written the following code .

```
import { useEffect, useRef, useState, useMemo } from "react";

function debounce(fn) {
    let timer = null;
    return function () {
        clearTimeout(timer);
        timer = setTimeout(fn, 1000)
    }
}

export default function () {

    const [value, setValue] = useState("");
    const myRef = useRef(handlChangeUtil);

    //it logs the value of state
    //closure : this is closed on 'value'
    function handlChangeUtil() {
        console.log(value);
    }


    //attaching the newer version of handChangeUtil function to myRef
    //since the mounted function won't have the newer value;
    useEffect(() => {
        myRef.current = handlChangeUtil;
    }, [value]);

    //it should return the debounced function during the mounting only

    const handlChangeUtilDebounce = useMemo(() => {

        //this code works
        // const func = () => {
        //     myRef.current();
        // }

        // return debounce(func)

        //this code doesnt't work
        return debounce(myRef.current);
    } , []);


    function handleChange(e) {
        setValue(e.target.value);
        handlChangeUtilDebounce();
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <input value={value} onChange={handleChange} />
        </div>
    )

    }
```

In the useMemo if i return debounce(myRef.current) it will always log the inital value of state i.e "" . However if i call myRef.current() inside the function , and pass that function in debounce (refer the code) , it's executing the updated value of state. What is the difference in both the codes?

Answer (score -1):

`useMemo` caches your last result of the function and returns it again and again as long as the value of the dependency array is changed.

In this scenario, you didn't add any dependency key to it, actually, if you pass `myRef.current` as a dependency key to it, it doesn't work again because `ref` object changes don't affect react rerender

For more info please read these pages: 
https://react.dev/reference/react/useMemo 
https://react.dev/reference/react/useRef